# AngularJS, config phase with asynchronus data

Tags: ajax, angularjs, durandal

I am currently trying to retrieve data asynchronously (from the database or server), before the module main application is started. Possibly through a provider called in .config. However, according to the documentation AngularJS, the services can not be recalled during this stage because not yet been instantiated.

Do this with other frameworks, such as DurandalJS, is very simple as in the configuration phase you can evaluate the promise. In the latter DurandalJS "will be waiting."

Do you know a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use resolve property in the route.

Comment: The solution "resolve" would work if I'm browsing in a state, correct? However, during the configuration I'm navigating to any state, indeed, I have to decide where to go based on the response to a call to the server, then async.

Comment: Looks like you need to return a promise in the `run` callback

Comment: So you can start angular yourself after the data is back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

you already answered your question.

> according to the documentation AngularJS, the services can not be recalled 
>   during this stage because not yet been instantiated